# SpriteKit background image scrolling flickers at seam line

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit

I am creating a 2D macOS game using SpriteKit and I want a continuous scrolling background from left to right.

I have a background image that is the same size as my frame. The image is duplicated side-by-side: initially the left one is centred and the right is off-screen. Both images (`SKSpriteNode`) are animated to slide across the screen and then reset their positions once moved by a full frame-width.

Here is the relevant code:

```swift
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var background = SKSpriteNode()

    func makeBackground() {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg-empty")
        let scroll = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -texture.size().width, dy: 0), duration: 30)
        let reset = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: texture.size().width, dy: 0), duration: 0)
        let animation = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([scroll, reset]))

        for idx in 0...1 {
            background = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
            background.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(idx)*texture.size().width, y: self.frame.midY)
            background.zPosition = -1
            background.run(animation)
            self.addChild(background)
        }
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {        
        makeBackground()
    }    
}
```

Although this works, I notice a black (~1 pixel vertical strip) flicker that appears ad-hoc at the seam of the connection.

What is causing this flicker and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encountering floating point rounding errors.  This is going to lead to a situation where your first BG rounds down, and your second BG rounds up, giving you a 1 pixel gap.

instead, try the following code

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var background = SKNode()

    func makeBackground() {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg-empty")
        let scroll = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -texture.size().width, dy: 0), duration: 30)
        let reset = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: texture.size().width, dy: 0), duration: 0)
        let animation = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([scroll, reset]))

        for idx in 0...1 {
            let subNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
            subNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(idx)*texture.size().width, y: self.frame.midY)

            background.addChild(subNode)
        }
        background.zPosition = -1
        background.run(animation)
        self.addChild(background)
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {        
        makeBackground()
    }    
}
```

Now you can avoid the gap because you are not running 2 different actions.

If you want to be able to scroll both ways. then place a texture to the left of your bg.

This will place a background node before and after your main background, and essentially turn it into 1 big node, with only the middle texture showing in its entirety.

If you have multiple background images, then just place the last frame of your background also to the left